# How to include multiple class files and .Jar files in class path which exist in sub folders in linux?

Tags: java, apache, lucene

How to include multiple class files and .Jar files in class path , i am on linux  .. and want to integrate lucene packages downloaded with my code , all libraries and class files are in lucene dirc. ( they are multiple sub-directories inside that folder ) ?

```
HelloLucene.java:1: error: package org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
                                          ^
HelloLucene.java:10: error: package org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
                                            ^
HelloLucene.java:11: error: package org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic does not exist
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
                                            ^
HelloLucene.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
                                                             ^
  symbol:   class ParseException
  location: class HelloLucene
    HelloLucene.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
    ^
  symbol:   class StandardAnalyzer
  location: class HelloLucene
HelloLucene.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class StandardAnalyzer
  location: class HelloLucene
HelloLucene.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
                  ^
  symbol:   class QueryParser
  location: class HelloLucene
Note: HelloLucene.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
7 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:xyz.jar**:**path_to_abc.jar.jar"
```

You basically have to append to the classpath, all the new entries that you want. To do so, just make use of ':' in linux and ';' in windows.

Comment: but how does it recursively include all jar files and class files ?

Comment: export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:directory" directory: the directory from where jars are picked recursively(directory containing all list of jar files.

Comment: how do i find if all files are included included ? i executed the command in terminal and run my prgm , it still gives me an eroor

Comment: Can you edit the post and tell me wht is the error that you get?

Comment: well , all the import files such as " import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;" doesn't load ..i mean the packages , do i need be root to use export command ?

Comment: I get it now, tell me the complete path of the directory where lucene-core-4.3.1.jar is placed in your local machine.It would ideally be inside the directory where you have downloaded lucene. 'place where u downloaded lucene/lucene/core'

Comment: "/home/neetish/lucene-4.3.1"   i just want to run a java file which uses all java packages and class files in lucene-4.3.1  folder

Comment: copy paste this command in terminal and on the same terminal try running your stuff:

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/neetish/lucene-4.3.1/core/lucene-core-4.3.1.jar

Just one last thing, can you cross verify that "/home/neetish/lucene-4.3.1/core/lucene-core-4.3.1.jar" existing in your local.

Comment: well , thanks a lot , i was getting 47 errors initially because all packages were not included ... i executed what  y6ou said , i get 7 errors now , some files and some packages are not loaded i guess

Comment: well , i have edited the post with the 7 errors which i am getting

Comment: Download this jar and set it up in the classpath as you did above. This should resolve all.http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/jarClasses/37782

Comment: @zerocool OP is clearly using Lucene 4.3.1, how would including v1.4.2 possibly do anything but make matters worse?

Comment: @codevetaNeetz - The errors you have added involve classes not contained in the Lucene-core jar.  So, do the similarly to before, to add `lucene-analyzers-common-4-3-1.jar` and `lucene-queryparser-4-3-1.jar`.  Another lucene jar that is very typically needed is `lucene-queries-4-3-1.jar`, though the errors you've indicated don't show any need for it at this point.

Comment: @femtoRgon tried what you said still getting the errors , still not solved

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the paths to the folders where the jars are located and recursively the inner jars are picked.